# Acceleration of servo motor with AASD-30A

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, acceleration, servo

I am using a servo motor 130st-M15015LB with the AASD-30A driver.
I have to use the acceleration with position control mode.
I can see in the documentation that If I use Pn110 to Pn112, I can have a time of acceleration between 5 to 1750ms, but when I try, it doesn't work, (it works until 500ms +-), I have been trying to solve this problem for one week, but I really don't understand (I'm a software developer).
If someone can help me, that would be great!

Example, I tried:

With the combination of Pn110 = 400,
Pn111 = 300,
Pn112 = 100 It works,

but when I put
Pn110 = 1500,
Pn111 = 1200,
Pn112 = 300 It doesn't work, the AASD-30A driver say that I cannot use these parameters,

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: And what happens when you go outside the operating range of the acceleration time?

Comment: I controle with some codes (modbus communication), so I receive error from the driver (slave), so when I go over 500, It said "Slave reported illegal data value" and it doesn't run the motor.
But according to the document, I can go up to 1750

Comment: As far as I understood from what I read on the Internet, most of the parameters (112 and 113 for example) are paired, that is, one is responsible for the parameters when rotating in one direction, the other, respectively, in the other direction. But there is some really useful information on these drives, I didn't study them well. When setting up controllers (once upon a time), I tried to identify the relationship between the parameters, trying to achieve the desired settings for my purposes. And it was very painstaking, since one parameter is non-linearly dependent on the other.

Comment: So for each parameter, I have to ask me if there is a connection with these three acceleration parameters? Yes it's arduous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The servo motor and his driver are fake, so some registers didn't work, it's normal.